# Get WordPress metabox value before header is output

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm writing a sort of 301 redirecting plugin for WordPress, which adds a metabox for each page, where you can enter a URL you want to redirect that page to. The value of this field has to be obtained before the header is output or else it's too late to redirect. Is it possible to get a metabox value before the header is output? How?

Comment: Why cant you use the `htaccess` file to update the URL? Or better yet you could use the 301 redirecting plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

Comment: Because 1. I'm writing a standalone plugin that should be able to handle this on it's own and 2. It's redirecting mobile devices only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal place to do this is with a hook into the [template_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action. The WP object is already set up, and no output has been generated yet.